# RecordId is not getting populated in LWC JS file

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to use recordId imperatively and do some logic based on that. But I can see `recordId` get printed in UI(for testing eg eg. 502i088888ABC23K)  with `{recordId}`

But when I try to use the recordId which is Case.Id to call Apex class, recordId is not getting populated in Js file.. Any help is appreciated.

Update : added this.recordId but its coming as `undefined`
This is a record page I am using LWC on top of that.

Update 2: REMOVING THE SET TIMEOUT SOLVED THE ISSUE.

```
import getRecord from '@salesforce/apex/CaseServiceController.getCaseWithRecordId';

const FIELDS = ['Case.First_Name__c','Case.Last_Name__c'];

export default class RedirectToRecordPage extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId; // its printing in HTML eg. 502i088888ABC23K
  @track record;
  @track error;

  connectedCallback(){
       setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('testing inside block');
          console.log('outside this.recordId :',this.recordId);
          getRecord({idx : this.recordId})
                .then(result => {
                    this.record = result;
                        // do logic with retrieved data
                    console.log('results,', result);
                    console.log('inside block this.recordId:',this.recordId);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log('error,', e);
                    this.error = e;
                })
        //code to be executed after 10 second
      }, 10000); // 10 Second
  }    

}
```

Comment: you can [edit] your question with new info (your `console.log()` statements/debugging). It's much easier to read than in comments. Also, where is this component on? A record page? A quick action?

Comment: This is a Record page and Edited above

Comment: any reason why the code is wrapped in `setTimeout`? Is that 10 seconds delay actually needed? Also, is that actually how you did the console logs? It shouldn't have commas to add the variables: `console.log('outside this.recordId : ' + this.recordId)`.

Comment: Removing the Set Time out Works !! thanks Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Call Apex Methods Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative) shows the format for doing this with parameters with this example

```javascript
handleSearch() {
    findContacts({ searchKey: this.searchKey })
        .then((result) => {
            this.contacts = result;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        });
}
```

You'll notice to pass in variables from your javascript file, you'll need to reference it as so `this.yourVariableName`. You're currently doing `'recordId'`. Changing it to the following should work

```javascript
getRecord({idx : this.recordId})
```

Comment: console.log('outside this.recordId : ', this.recordId);
            getRecord({idx : this.recordId})
                .then(result => {
                    this.record = result;
                    console.log('results,', result);
                    console.log('this.recordId : ', this.recordId);


both are coming as "undefine"
outside this.recordId :  undefined

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Kris Goncalves has said, the `setTimeout` is the final problem. It has a function specified as `function() {...}` which means that the `this` binding changes from being the LWC component to be the `window` object (which is the `this` binding for the call from `setTimeout`). Change this to use an arrow function, which doesn't change the `this` binding (leaving it as the LWC component) and the problem will evaporate:

```
connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        ...
    }, 10000);

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with @wire

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class WireFunction extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track record;
    @track error;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Name'] })
    wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }
    get name() {
        return this.record.fields.Name.value;
    }
}
```